# Bootstrap 3 - Fixed Column 300px and Skyscraper - Best Practice

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the best practice for add an fixed column with `300px` for sidebar and an optional `container` for a wide skyscraper?

```
| content - fluid | sidebar 300px fixed | skyscraper |
```

Should I scale down the `.container` class to a smaller fixed width (`160px` less) and set there a fixed column with `300px`? Is there an solution for this requirement, because it is a common problem - i think so ;-)